# Ordering position on Model during update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-list

I am using acts_as_list on my Product model, and trying to make it so you can manually edit the position. Currently if I edit Product 3 from position 3 to position 1, it won't adjust the other products

Example: Move Product from Position 3 to Position 1

ID   Name        Position 
1  Product          1  
2  Product          2 
3  Product           3

Will result to

ID   Name        Position 
1  Product          1  
2  Product          2 
3  Product           1

But I need it to result to

ID   Name        Position 
1  Product          2  
2  Product          3 
3  Product          1  

I've come to the conclusion I should add the code to my products update class. Here is what I have so far:

```
def update
#To edit acts_as_list manually, just get all items with a position higher 
#than the current item and increment each one.

#Find the product to be changed
@product = Product.find(params[:id])

#Find if there is a product already in the requested position
old_product = Product.find_by_position_and_category_id(params[:position], params[:category_id])



  #If the old product has a position less then the current product, return the products in between minus 1
  if @product.position > old_product.position
    products = Product.where(:product < @product.position, :product > @old_product.position)
    products.each do |product|
      product.position + 1
    end
  #If old product position is greater then current product position, return the products in between and decrement all position
  elsif old_product.position < @product.position
    products = Product.all
    products.each do |product|
      product.position = product.position - 1
    end
 end
```

In this code i'm trying to grab all the products withing the range of the old product and new product, then increment the position of all of them, but my code isn't working, It seems like the call old_product = Product.find_by_position_and_category_id(params[:position], params[:category_id]) keeps returning nil, when it should return the product with the position of the old product.

Thanks for any help, and let me know if i'm on the right track or if there is a easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb) provides helper methods to do this sort of thing without needing to add your own code. If you want to move your product from position 3 to position 1 and automatically reorder everything else, do this:

```
@product.insert_at(1)
```

Try that instead of manually changing the position and see if that doesn't simplify your code.

Comment: Wow thanks that helped a ton, I'm not sure why I didn't see that in the code earlier. It seems to work when I add it to a lower position, but when I change 1's position to 5 it doesn't sort. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't used acts_as_list myself for awhile, but I think that if you move a number lower than the lowest position it takes it for granted that's the position you wanted -- so if you have only three items and insert one of them at 5, it'll have 1, 2, 5. This doesn't really matter for the internal list representation though -- if you use Product.find_by_position(2).lower_item, I think it should still find the lower item correctly. I think.

Comment: What about if i'm trying to move a number to position of the lowest number, and not lower then it? So far it seems like it will just go ahead and assign the number to the lowest and not increment the others, so i'll be stuck with two numbers in position 1?

Comment: If you want to move a number to the lowest position, try ```@product.move_to_bottom```.

Comment: cool i'll just create an if statement to check if it's the lowest, and if it is just do move_to_bottom, right?